# Inconsistent match function, if I run twice works (R)

Tags: r, match, matching

I am trying to reorder a numeric vector `current_qty` using its name according to another vector `trade_order`.

After a simple match, they give me some weird arrangement.

```
current_qty <- getQuantity(trades)
print(names(current_qty))
[1] "ivvb11"       "lft20210301"  "ltn20180101"  "ntnb20200815" "pibb11"      
print(trade_order)
[1] "pibb11"       "ivvb11"       "lft20210301"  "ntnb20200815" "ltn20180101" 
current_qty <- current_qty[match(names(current_qty), trade_order)]
print(current_qty)
lft20210301  ltn20180101     pibb11 ntnb20200815       ivvb11 
     2.15        42.59        50.00         3.89        60.00
```

Now the funny part. If I run the same match function twice. It works.

```
current_qty <- getQuantity(trades)
print(names(current_qty))
[1] "ivvb11"       "lft20210301"  "ltn20180101"  "ntnb20200815" "pibb11"      
print(trade_order)
[1] "pibb11"       "ivvb11"       "lft20210301"  "ntnb20200815" "ltn20180101" 
current_qty <- current_qty[match(names(current_qty), trade_order)]
current_qty <- current_qty[match(names(current_qty), trade_order)]
print(current_qty)
pibb11       ivvb11  lft20210301 ntnb20200815  ltn20180101 
50.00        60.00         2.15         3.89        42.59
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: yes, you can use `%in%`.From the help file: `%in%`  is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help(match)`:

"match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second."

So it looks at each element in `names(current_qty)` and returns the position of it in `trade_order`.  So for example it sees `"ivvb11"` in the second position on `trade_order`.  Then this gets passed to your subset where it reorders things.  So what this will do is it will move the element in position 2 of `current_qty` (`"lft20210301"`) to the first position.

Thus, you can see that you should reverse the order of the args you pass to match and you will be fine:

`current_qty[match(trade_order, names(current_qty))]`

Comment: Thank you. I was misleaded because the other vector I tried to arrange worked by coincidence. I am such a moron.